# Code works fine, just want to know why I don't need a set method for Perimeter and Area but for width and length

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle {

    private double length, width;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Rectangle(double length, double width){
        this.length = length;
        this.width  = width;
    }
    public void setLength(double l){
        length = l;
    }
    public double getLength(){
        return length;
    }
    public void setWidth(double w){
        w = width;
    }
    public double getWidth(){
        return width;
    }
    public double getArea(){
        return length*width;
    }
    public double getPerimeter(){
        return ((2*length) + (2*width));`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Why don't I need a set method for Area and Perimeter? Also does it matter if you make the code this.length = length as compared to length = l?

Comment: because your are is equal to your length * width. if you do setArea(10) what should length width be? could be l = 1, w = 10 or l = 2, w = 5, or l = 10, w = 1 etc. same argument for a setPerimeter method

Comment: your `setWidth()` function is wrong. It should be `width = w;` not `w = width;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it this way: how would you implement a setter for the perimeter or the area property?

There is no good way of doing it that would make reasonable sense to users of your class: let's say the width is 10 and the height is 7, and a call arrives to set the perimeter to 24. Would you adjust the height, the width, or both in order to satisfy the new value of the perimeter? There is no usable solution to this problem.

Area and Perimeter are so-called *calculated properties*, i.e. properties computed from values of *settable properties*. That is why neither area nor perimeter can have a setter.